# How to create wrapper REST API for social login in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a wrapper REST API for Firebase Authentication using cloud functions.

How can I *create user* or *authenticate user* on Firebase once I have the Facebook Access token on client (using Facebook SDK)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Firebase Functions with HTTP triggers, you can use firebase.js client node.js library  to authenticate a user and return the Firbease tokens in your REST API. You would send the Facebook Access token to that HTTP endpoint, sign in the user with `signInWithCredential` using node.js client library and return the ID token and refresh token.

If you want to use REST API:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"postBody":"access_token=[FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN]&providerId=[facebook.com]","requestUri":"[http://localhost]","returnIdpCredential":true,"returnSecureToken":true}'
```

This would return the Firebase ID token and refresh token:

```
{
  "idToken": "[ID_TOKEN]",
  "refreshToken": "[REFRESH_TOKEN]",
  ...
}
```

This is all you need for a Firebase Auth session.

To construct the user, call the following API with the ID token:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"idToken":"[FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN]"}'
```

This would return the user and the data associated:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse",
  "users": [
    {
      "localId": "ZY1rJK0...",
      "email": "user@example.com",
      "emailVerified": false,
      "displayName": "John Doe",
      "providerUserInfo": [
        {
          "providerId": "password",
          "displayName": "John Doe",
          "photoUrl": "http://localhost:8080/img1234567890/photo.png",
          "federatedId": "user@example.com",
          "email": "user@example.com",
          "rawId": "user@example.com",
          "screenName": "user@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "photoUrl": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg",
      "passwordHash": "...",
      "passwordUpdatedAt": 1.484124177E12,
      "validSince": "1484124177",
      "disabled": false,
      "lastLoginAt": "1484628946000",
      "createdAt": "1484124142000",
      "customAuth": false
    }
  ]
}
```

To refresh the ID token after it expires, use the refresh token returned:
With REST API:

```
curl 'https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=[REFRESH_TOKEN]'
```

This would return a new ID token and refresh token:

```
{
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "refresh_token": "[REFRESH_TOKEN]",
  "id_token": "[ID_TOKEN]",
  "user_id": "tRcfmLH7o2XrNELi...",
  "project_id": "1234567890"
}
```

To use this with client library on the backend:
`var firebase = require('firebase');`

You send the FB access token from the client to your HTTP endpoint and sign-in with it:

```
var cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbAccessToken);
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).then(function(user) {
  // User is obtained here.
  // To get refresh token:
  // user.refreshToken
  // To get ID token:
  return user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
    // ...
  })
}).catch(function(error) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please give more details?  We don't want to use any Firebase libraries on front end client. Is it possible to just pass the facebook access token (which is retrieved via FB SDK on client) and do the rest of the process of login on Firebase Cloud functions?

Comment: It is possible to do so, though I don't recommend it. Honestly this is pretty straight forward. I will add the HTTP API to call to my original answer.

Comment: I don't see a way to signin or signout via Admin SDK. Can you please explain how its possible?

Comment: I don't understand the context. I think you should open another post about this. Admin SDK doesn't have a notion of sign in/ sign out.

Comment: Whats should be the exact value for the "requestUri" in the above http call ? It should be just the localhost or to be replaced with some other value.